# Multiple file server syncing

Tags: networking, sync, samba, dropbox

Here is my setup :

- Office 1 : 20 users a dropbox sharing between all
- Office 2 : 9 users, sharing the same dropbox to share the files

My problem : Office 2 is in remote place and gets only a 4G connection, we reach record high traffic because of the constant update of dropbox files.

My idea :
I get a PC in each office with Samba share that local user access through local network, then both file server are synced with dropbox

My second problem : Dropbox is not syncing files if they are modified though Samba (something to do with `inotify`). I assumed Owncloud has the same issue

My second idea:
get one owncloud network in each office, all local user syncing to it. Then get the 2 Owncloud servers to sync.

That way, I would got only one file exchange through the 4G connection rather than 9.

Question :
How to do that? is that even a valid solution?

Comment: Is a domain environment? You may consider [BranchCache](https://technet.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/dd637832(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it looks not bad at first glance, but we do not have windows server, only Linux servers and NAS, so I am limited here. Also, what about Win 8.1 and Win 10, it does not look clear in the explanation. I still dig into that direction to see if that is possible.

Comment: I am not familiar with Linux so I dont have idea on it, if you are working at workgroup environment, you can still using BranCache in DISTRIBUTED Mode [Details](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649211(v=ws.10).aspx), it depends on your network infrastructure how many PC is running windows and how often you access the same file

Comment: What NAS? The Synology, for example not only is able to sync Dropbox to itself but also has its own sync tool so that your users would sync to the NAS and the NAS's could sync to DB!

Comment: NAS, we have Synology and Qnap in Office 1 and Buffalo in Office 2. Let me have a look there too

Comment: Add a comment for anybody who ends up here : the final solution I implemented is : Owncloud server in Office1, files shared through Samba in Office1, then in Office 2, a PC with Owncloud client, syncing to our Owncloud server, the files are then locally shared through Samba. I can update later upon request on the issue we meet (so far none as just started)